# Mysql, addition raws from two different tables, get all the content from the first table and only the curdate content from the second table

Tags: mysql, select, addition

I have two different tables **a** and **ah**.
**a** is the article stock quantity, **ah** is the article stock movement.

I would like to have all the rows from  **a** and only the current date (today) movement row from **ah** and add two columns. I've tried a few things, one of them being right join but I only get articles that had a movement today. Please Could you help?

I've tried this:

```
SELECT a.numero,
       a.stockDay, 
       date(ah.dateCreation), 
       ah.creationDate, 
       SUM(a.stockDay + ah.diffQuantite) AS 'stockReel' 
FROM article a, articleLotHisto ah 
WHERE ah.articleId = a.id 
AND date(ah.dateCreation) = CURDATE();
```

Also that:

```
SELECT a.numero, 
       a.stockDay, 
       date(ah.dateCreation), 
       ah.dateCreation, 
       SUM(a.stockDay + ah.diffQuantite) AS 'stockReel' 
FROM article a
RIGHT JOIN articleLotHisto ah
ON ah.articleId = a.id
WHERE date(ah.dateCreation) = CURDATE();
```

But I always get only the rows that have been created today and not the complete a table.

Comment: Could you add some sample data from the 2 tables to enable testing? That said, if I understand your need correctly, you probably want to LEFT JOIN a selection from **ah** with the relevant date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering table **ah** on the date BEFORE joining it to **a** should do what you want; try this:

```
SELECT a.numero, 
       a.stockDay, 
       date(ah.dateCreation), 
       ah.dateCreation, 
       a.stockDay + COALESCE(ah.diffQuantite, 0) AS 'stockReel' 
FROM article a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM articleLotHisto
            WHERE date(dateCreation) = CURDATE()
            ) ah
ON ah.articleId = a.id
```

Edit: added `COALESCE` for articles with no movement today.

Comment: Dear Swifty, thanks a lot for the quick response. That's amazing, it's exactly what I wanted to have. I could have never come up with a such a query.

Comment: You're welcome; and don't worry, with practice and tutorial look ups, you'll learn all about CTEs, temporary tables and such.

Answer (score 0):

I've just added a "sum" and a "group by", because we can have more than one movement per day and we want them to be sum up.
Here is the query you gave me. Line 18,19,20 is the same article number with each time a -2 quantity move result is 58 it should be 54[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us2Ra.png):

Here I added a sum and a group by the result is correct. Thanks again for your help :-)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgDVi.png)

Comment: Nice; indeed I had not envisioned the possibility of several movements the same day. I imagine my request added '-2' on 3 rows, instead of `3 * (-2)` on one row.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).